# the metaphysical, or, in its highest sense, the physical

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

The following is from *Frankenstein*. I'd like to know why "phsyical" is regarded as the highest sense of "metaphysical":

> . . . my inquiries were directed to the metaphysical, or, in its highest sense, the physical secrets of the world.

Comment: the physical in its highest sense = metaphysical

Comment: As you know, metaphysical means that which cannot be reached through objective studies.  Frankie wants to learn about stuff that is beyond the grasp of current knowledge.

Comment: @kevin012 It's the other way around. Physical is the hhighest sense of metaphysical, according to the sentence.

Comment: @Apollyon I agree with Kevin. "The physical secrets of the world, in it's highest sense." is the metaphysical. Although, it hardly matters, since it's 19th century blather.

Comment: What does "its" in "in its highest sense" refer to?

Comment: @Apollyon "The physical secrets of the world". Note that the "or" is equivalent to "=", so the two sides of the "or" are equated. The number of "secrets" doesn't seem to agree with "its", but I think the phrase "the physical secrets of the world" is considered as a unitary thing in that sentence.

Comment: Would it be grammatically correct if the "its" referred to "metaphysical"?

Comment: He wants to study metaphysics in its (metaphysics') highest sense, that being the physical secrets of the world

Comment: If the sentence means the metaphysical secrets of the world, 'it' doesn't refer to 'metaphysical' because 'metaphysical' is an adjective. Metaphysics is a study that is more fundamental than the study of the phenomenon in the physical world so it makes sense 'the metaphysical' to be the highest sense of the physical.

Comment: I disagree. I think from the way the sentence is written that "its highest sense" is referring to the 'metaphysical'. How higher could you go in metaphysics than something that is *actually real*? It couldn't be the other way round: the highest point as something completely impossible.

Comment: ...and metaphysics *certainly* isn't the highest point in physics, more like the lowest, if it could be called physics at all.

Comment: @WeatherVane What Frankie interested was the soul of humans which was not physics. What he was interested in was the secret which was forbidden to be studied. It's not the ordinary phenomenon of nature. He was asking the truth behind nature. It's not just physical secrets. His study was metaphysical.

Comment: You guys should really settle on the meaning of "the highest sense" before determining what the "its" refers to.